# Automate .NET form login with python

Tags: python, .net

Is there some way to open a .NET form app from a python script that passes data to preform operations in the .NET form app like automate a login process?
I have been reading about the subprocess module and I could open the app but I don't know how to pass de credentials from the script to the app, any idea of what can I do?

Comment: Do you have access to modify the .NET app yourself?

Comment: How would you execute the .NET application if you weren't using Python?  If you can do it via the command-line, odds are good that you can automate this using a Python subprocess.